# iOS Delay an action happening again

Tags: ios

So i have a random number generator built in a forumla with arc4random.
So the forumla has 3 variables

```
Variable 1 > User enters it
Variable 2 > User enters it
Variable 3 > arc4random
```

My question is how can i tell arc4random to create the SAME number if variable 1&2 is the same

```
So if
V1 = 5
V2 = 4
V3 = 68 and the user enters 5&4 it shall create 68 again, BUT after 10 minutes it may use another random number
```

Sry had to put that as code because it wouldnt have letted me upload this question otherwise

Comment: Do you understand what `arc4random` does? It generates a random seedless number. It will most likely *never* generate the same number twice in a users time using the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have understood: You want to ask 2 numbers and another one to be generated by arc4random but if the user introduces the same 2 numbers during the next ten minutes, the arc4random number must be equal.

I will try to save the numbers in other variables (saveV1, saveV2 and saveV3 for example) and start an NSTimer with the time interval 600 seconds. The NSTimer's selector will clean the saveVX variables. So this is the structure:

```
    1. Ask V1 
    2. Ask V2
    3. Check if there are saved numbers and check if they are V1 == saveV1 and V2 == saveV2
    4A. If they are the same: V3 = saveV3 
    4B. If they aren't: Generate V3
    5. Save V1, V2, V3 in saveV1, saveV2 and saveV3.
```

Is this what you were asking for?

EDITED: 
Here is the code:

```
//v1, v2, v3, saveV1, saveV2, saveV3 declared in the .h file
-(void) function
{
  v1 = [[v1TextField text] intValue];
  v2 = [[v2TextField text] intValue];

if(v1 == saveV1 && v2 == saveV2) 
{
  v3 = saveV3;
}
else
{
  v3 = arc4random()%100; //This line generates a random number between 0 and 99.
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600.0f target:self selector:@selector(deleteVs)   userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

saveV1 = v1;
saveV2 = v2;
saveV3 = v3;

NSLog(@"V1: %d, V2: %d, V3: %d",v1,v2,v3);

}

-(void)deleteVs
{
saveV1 = 0;
saveV2 = 0;
saveV3 = 0;
//You can change this and put -1 to have 0 as a valid value of v1 and v2.
}
```

Comment: @Mershual I have edited my answer with the code. I have not tried this code because I cannot.

Comment: - (IBAction)Lange{
        float f = arc4random_uniform(3) ;  
        float x = ([valueOne.text floatValue]-1.5)/1.5;
        float c = (5+[valueTwo.text floatValue])/2;
        float o = (x+c)/2+f;
       
        total.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.fcm", o]; } How should i edit your code so its working?

Comment: change the type of v1,v2,v3 and saveV1,saveV2 and saveV3 to float. these are the equivalences: x -> v1, c -> v2 and f -> v3. We will add a new variable named v4 or o which is your o. Finally, substitute the NSLog line by your total.text line.

Comment: 1. implementation file http://i46.tinypic.com/1p8ndf.png .h http://i45.tinypic.com/2yl5qpw.png ... Can you tell me what i did wrong? :/ (Would move this to discussion but i do not have enough reputation)

Comment: @Mershual mmm.. Well let me say to you that you have completely wrong concepts... I know you won't like this but I think it is better to start from the beginning reading about Objective-C or C. You have used your variables before declare them, you don't know how does an if statement work... I really think this is not the way to do the things

Comment: Im a beginner in process, any sites where i should start from?

Comment: I am also a beginner, I read "iPhone and iPad apps for absolute beginners" and "Beginning iPhone 4 development". Both of them are from Apress.

Comment: If i purchase these books, should i wait till there out for iOS 6 as iOS 6 will most likely come out in some months, or should i buy it just now for iOS 5? (As a tipp from you)

Comment: I am nearly completely sure there are newer and more updated books but I started reading those books and then you can improve by your own. I think you can search something for iOS5 (because I got those books at the iOS4 last days) and it will be OK for iOS6.